# MySQL error while creating tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, structure

I have an error in my database

```
Error: Invalid structure on line 18. Refer to our Manual (PHPMYADMIN)
```

I use (WAMPSERVER 2 32bits)
-PHPMYADMIN
- MYSQL 5.5.6
- PHP 5

Although i need to use InnoDB (`ENGINE=InnoDB`)

thanks to help me. Take a look at the **structure**... the variable name meaning is not important.

Here's my code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Adresse;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Telephone;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Personne;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TelPers;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Specialiste;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Patient;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ListePatient;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Produit;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Medicament;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Materiel;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Panier;

CREATE TABLE Adresse(
idAdresse   INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
num         INT(5) NOT NULL,
rue         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
ville           VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
postal      VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Telephone(
idTel           INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
typeTel     VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
ind         INT(3) NOT NULL,
quartier        INT(3) NOT NULL,
num         INT(4) NOT NULL,
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Personne(
idPersonne      INT(100) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nom             VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
prenom          VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
idTel               INT(100) NOT NULL,
idAdresse       INT(100) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(idAdresse) REFERENCES Adresse(idAdresse),
FOREIGN KEY(idTel) REFERENCES Telephone(idTel)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE TelPers(
idPersonne      INT(100) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
idTel               INT(100) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(idPersonne) REFERENCES Personne(idPersonne),
FOREIGN KEY(idTel) REFERENCES Telephone(idTel)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Specialiste(
login           VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
password    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
profession  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
idListeP        INT(5),
idPanier        INT(5),
idPersonne  INT(100),
FOREIGN KEY(idPersonne) REFERENCES Personne(idPersonne)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Patient(
idPatient    INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
sexe            CHAR NOT NULL,
anniv           DATE,
assurance   INT(3) NOT NULL,
idPersonne  INT(100),
FOREIGN KEY(idPersonne) REFERENCES Personne(idPersonne)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE ListePatient(
idListeP        INT(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
idPatient   INT(10)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
FOREIGN KEY(idListeP) REFERENCES Specialiste(idListeP),
FOREIGN KEY(idPatient) REFERENCES Patient(idPatient)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Produit(
idProduit       INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
nom         VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
descr           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
prix            DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
qte         INT(100) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Medicament(
idMedic         INT(100)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
marque      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
typeMed     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
idProduit       INT(100) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(idProduit) REFERENCES Produit(idProduit)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Materiel(
idMateriel  INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
rabais      INT(99) NOT NULL,                       
idProduit   INT(100) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(idProduit) REFERENCES Produit(idProduit)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Panier(
idPanier        INT(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
idProduit       INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
FOREIGN KEY(idPanier) REFERENCES Specialiste(idPanier),
FOREIGN KEY(idProduit) REFERENCES Produit(idProduit)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP! :D

Comment: Well if we dont have the error. its kind of useless....

Comment: Agreed. Please post the error that you are encountering to help point someone in the right direction.

Comment: Error: Invalid structure on line 18. Refer to our Manual (PHPMYADMIN)

Comment: I edit my answer look to the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In `Telephone` declaration there is a comma (`,`) before closing `)`
2. In `TelPers` there are two primary keys
3. In `Specialiste` there is `PRIMARY KEY` twice in `login` column
4. In `ListePatien` there are two primary keys
5. In `Panier` there are two primary keys

To define a PRIMARY key on two columns use

```
CREATE TABLE Panier(
idPanier        INT(5) NOT NULL,
idProduit       INT(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idPanier`,`idProduit`),
FOREIGN KEY(idPanier) REFERENCES Specialiste(idPanier),
FOREIGN KEY(idProduit) REFERENCES Produit(idProduit)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

(same on other tables)

Comment: for the 2 primary keys i want to mixed up 2 variable to make one pk

Comment: you are a boss i will test it in 2 hours and get back to this.